# Display months on XAxis using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm developing one chart related to months and days.
On my XAxis, I have days, but I need to show titles only for the first day of the month.
For instance, if my range starts from 23rd November and ends on 12 January, I need to show the titles starting from 1st December, 1st January...
Overall, I need to show an interval, not from the beginning of the diagram.

For now, I tried to show all values on the XAxis and format them only if this value is the first day of the month, but it sounds like a workaround.

Don't somebody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create IAxisValueFormatter implement. Inside you need to find the first day of month. For example with [JodaTime](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android):

```
val startOfMonth = DateTime(Date()).withDayOfMonth(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay()
```

Next get your locale with:

```
private val locale = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration).get(0)
```

And use SimpleDateFormat in getFormattedValue (IAxisValueFormatter implementation):

```
SimpleDateFormat("d MMM", locale).format(startOfMonth.toDate())
```